# Collections.unmodifiableCollection return value

Tags: java

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
List<Integer> integers2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
Collection<Integer> integers3 = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(integers);
Collections.unmodifiableCollection(integers2);
integers3.add(3);
integers2.add(3);
```

I understand that executing `integers3.add()` will throw an UnsupportedOperationException, but integers2 has not changed the instance. I looked at the source code of Collections.unmodifiableCollection (Collection ..), but the implementation of integers2 also throws an UnsupportedOperationException from the AbstractList. Why is this?

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` return a fixed-size list as documented on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...), so you can't call `add()` on it.

Comment: Just because you _make_ a collection unmodifiable doesn't mean it wasn't _already_ unmodifiable.

Answer (score 7):

It is not because of using `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(integers2);`. 
It is because Arrays.asList() returns a fixed size array which cannot be changed. This is first few lines of the doc for asList() method.

```
/**
 * Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.  (Changes to
 * the returned list "write through" to the array.)  This method acts
 * as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in
 * combination with {@link Collection#toArray}.  The returned list is
 * serializable and implements {@link RandomAccess}.
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the documentation of `Arrays::asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) shows that

> The returned list implements the optional `Collection` methods, except those that would change the size of the returned list. Those methods leave the list unchanged and throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Looking further at [the documentation of `Collection:add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) reveals that

> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (**optional operation**).

Since the call `integers2.add(3);` would change the size of `integers2`, the call throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I didn't realize before that there is an ArrayList under Array class, which doesn't override the add method from abstractlist